# multitask restart app

Tags: iphone, ios

My application has setting in Settings.

User may change the setting.

After user apply the changes and launch the app. because the application launched before and it support multitask so the changes applied into the setting, will not apply into the application. Unless the user close the task and relaunch the app.

So I would implement if statement into the application to do:

if (settingBool == 1){
   'restarted the application'
} else {
   'Multitask keep working'
}

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could tell your app that there could be new settings in `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`
Set a flag or send a notification that tells every object that has cached settings to read them again from the NSUserDefaults

Comment: thanks for your trying. I know that, but I want after applicationDidBecomeActive appear do restart the application. How can I implement that?

Comment: you can't restart your app. You can "end" your app with exit(0); but this looks like a crash to users, you will receive a bazillion emails about it and if apples review team finds it they will most likely reject your app. And you can't start your app. The user has to start it again